# how to make whole node of d3 tree layout clickable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 tree layout,nodes of which are repalced with certain images,problem is only on some portion of the image is clickable not on entire image,functions which are configured for onclick are working only when we click on that certain portion.

how to make entire image as clickable

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: Thank you Lars for Responding .using a ccs class I am able to achieve it..